# Can c++ std::source_location be used with a conversion operator?

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm trying to add debug instrumentation in C++.  I want to probe all changes to a variable.  To do that, I'm using the c++20 `std::source_location::current()` feature, like this member function:

```
void DoubleWithProbe::set(double newValue, std::source_location loc = std::source_location::current())
{
    std::cout << "Changed: new = " << newValue << ", old = " << m_value
        << " (" << loc.file_name() << ":"
        << loc.line() << ")" << std::endl;
    m_value = newValue;
}
```

However, this requires the caller to use a set function. If I try to use operators, the pattern fails:

```
operator double(std::source_location loc = std::source_location::current()) const
{
    std::cout << "Accessed: value = " << m_value <<
            << " (" << loc.file_name() << ":"
            << loc.line() << ")" << std::endl;
    return m_value;
}
DoubleWithProbe& operator=(double newValue, std::source_location loc = std::source_location::current())
{
    ...
}
```

These are both illegal because `operator double` may not have arguments and `operator=` must have only one argument.  For `operator=`, I've found this workaround:

```
    struct DoubleAndLoc
    {
        double m_val;
        std::source_location m_loc;
        // not explicit.
        DoubleAndLoc(double val, std::source_location loc = std::source_location::current())
            : m_val(val), m_loc(loc)
        {
        }
    };
    DoubleWithProbe& operator=(DoubleAndLoc newValue)
    {
        ...
    }
```

This is probably ok for doubles, but for strings, this would quickly run into double-conversion issues.

Is there any way to make `operator double()` work, and any way to make `operator=()` work more cleanly?

A working example is at https://godbolt.org/z/4Ea1sPT1n.

Comment: `but for strings, this would quickly run into double-conversion issues.` what "double-conversion issues"?

Comment: If I was probing a std::string instead of a double, this wouldn't work:
  x = "xxx";
struct StringAndLoc
{
    std::string m_val;
...

because it would convert once from const char * to std::string, then again from std::string to StringAndLoc.

Answer (score 9):

In [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20), no. But in [c++23](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b23)... still no.

---

A previous version of this answer used [deducing this](https://wg21.link/p0847) to be able to declare the conversion function like this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct RefWithLoc {
    T& t;
    std::source_location loc;

    RefWithLoc(T& t, std::source_location loc = std::source_location::currenct())
      : t(t)
      , loc(loc)
    { }
};

struct DoubleWithProbe {
    operator double(this RefWithLoc<DoubleWithProbe const> self);
};
```

However, this... doesn't work. [[over.best.ics.general]/4](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics.general#4) prohibits considering user-defined conversion sequences for the object parameter of a user-defined conversion function (on the principle that at most one conversion is allowed to happen).

With the above you could still write `dwp.operator double()`, but not `static_cast<double>(dwp)`.

Perhaps the fact that you can easily get this to work with a named conversion (even in [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20)) suggests that if the functionality is required, then you could just add a `to_double()` function?

Comment: Nice! I did find one other problem with my implementation since I posted: Assigning one probe to another doesn't work because I can't use Probe&operator=(const Probe &rhs) on the same types and get a value.  I have to delete the default assignment operator, then it will not find a different overload. I wonder if any of the C++23 stuff will help that.

Comment: Nice, but weird, what are the exact requirements on "this" argument? Only that it can be constructed from instance of DoubleWithProbe ? I guess this is nice, but quite hard to teach since this used to mean something totally different back in the old days(C++20).

Answer (score 1):

You can generalise your `DoubleAndLoc`, and then use a member function overloads instead of `operator =`.

```
template <typename T>
struct LocatedValue
{
    T m_val;
    std::source_location m_loc;
    // not explicit.
    LocatedValue(T val, std::source_location loc = std::source_location::current())
        : m_val(std::forward<T>(val)), m_loc(loc)
    {
    }
};

class StringWithProbe {
public:
    StringWithProbe& operator=(LocatedValue<const char *> newValue)
    {
        assign(newValue.m_val, newValue.m_loc);
        return *this;
    }
    StringWithProbe& operator=(LocatedValue<std::string> newValue)
    {
        assign(newValue.m_val, newValue.m_loc);
        return *this;
    }

private:
    void assign(const char * value, std::source_location loc)
    {
        //...
    }
    void assign(std::string value, std::source_location loc)
    {
        //...
    }
};
```

[See it on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2ff27386cb6eef56)

Comment: Yeah, that should fix any double-conversion issues that come up.  I can also make assign() use a template, so anything that legally converts to m_val will work.  Thank you.

Comment: Any thoughts on operator double()?

Comment: @RobL you can add `LocatedValue::operator T` which will do `operator double`, but not `operator std::string`